# How do older versions of an app cope with a newer core data model?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I understand that if I need to change my core data model I can add a version of the model and migrate from older to newer versions. But what happens if a user updates a copy of the app on one device but not the other and then adds data on the newer copy? How will the older version respond when it pulls those changes down from iCloud?

Comment: Have you tried creating a small sample app to do just this? You will find the answer for yourself that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older version will crash or at least throw an exception when you call `addPersistentStore...`.

This is a situation you will need to account for.

Comment: Thank you. I am already handling exceptions when adding the persistent store, but the handling at the moment just displays the core data error. In this situation should I ask the user to update to the latest version of the app when the error is detected?

Comment: I would put something in the metadata so you know what version you are working with and depending on your business model and user experience, asking them to update, letting them know they already updated on another device, etc. would be warranted.

Comment: Excellent idea. I'll implement that before release. Thanks again! :)